# No response from SKProductsResponse with In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

As in the title i'm not getting any response from SKProductsResponse.

How i am doin it :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //self.tableView.hidden = TRUE;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productsLoaded:) name:kProductsLoadedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:kProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchaseFailed:) name:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object: nil];

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus == NotReachable) 
    {        
        progressHud = [InAppProgressHud showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
        progressHud.labelText = @"Pas de connection internet";
        progressHud.detailsLabelText = @"Activez votre 3G ou le WIFI et rééssayez";
        //[self performSelector:@selector(dismissHUD:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
    } 
    else 
    {        
        if ([InAppPurchaseSingleton sharedHelper].Products == nil) 
        {
            [[InAppPurchaseSingleton sharedHelper] requestProducts];
            progressHud = [InAppProgressHud showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
            progressHud.labelText = @"Chargement...";
            [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];
        }
    }
}
```

My requests :

```
-(void)requestProducts 
{
    self.request = [[[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers] autorelease];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

And the response callback :

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)requestLocal didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response 
{  
    self.products = response.products;

    for (SKProduct *prod in self.Products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , prod.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , prod.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , prod.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , prod.productIdentifier);
    }
    self.request = nil;    
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:products];    
}
```

The problem is that the callback is never called, i get NO response, nothing happen. I'm not even getting error log, nothing =(

->I know that internet connexion is ok

->I tried on ios 5.1 simulator, AND on a device and i have the same result in both

->I'm logged out from Itunes connect

->My application BundleId : fr.eamdev.testapp

->Version : 0.2 in Prepare for Upload

->I have 3 IAP : fr.eamdev.testapp.package_1, fr.eamdev.testapp.package_2, fr.eamdev.testapp.package_3  // Non consummable // Cleared for sale : Yes // Ready to submit

Does anyone  have an idea, i'm quiet desesperate here TT.TT
So you know i already got through Troy Brant's In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough and Ray Wenderlich's tuto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check.

Try the 4.3 sim.
When I call this on the 4.3 sim, I get an error message in the log that says :-
2012-07-18 18:45:03.501 shadowslide[10598:13703] : Failing immediately in simulator

It works normally in the 5.1 sim.  This will tell you if you're getting the call out OK.

The code you've posted all looks good to me ( autorelease? not using ARC?), so I'm wondering if you maybe have a problem with the singleton ( hope you don't feel insulted :) ).  If the singleton creation fails, then the other calls will fail silently.  Since you're not storing the return from the singleton shared helper, you've won't have been able to check it in the debugger.

Hope this helps

Comment: I already tried 4.3 (since i had no idea what to do x). In the log i get the "4.3 simulator is not ok with In App Purchase" or so. And the result when i try to get my product list is the same. My time out method is called after 20seconds of waiting for the response. Tomorow i will debug my singleton is you adviced (i don't feel insulted at all) i didn't though it could be an allocation issue. I'm not using ARC since i'm using cocos2d i feel more confortable using the old way XD

Comment: I tested my singleton many times and didn't find anything suspicious. My variable "sharedHelperInstance" was allocated only one time  and correctly... BUT the last times i executed my application on the simulator IT WORKED and i don't understand why, i didn't changed anything in my code. I just tried to debug in step to step mode and with some debug log... Anyway now it's working properly thanks for your answer.